# Permalinks with mod_rewrite on custom site build

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, permalinks

I am trying to get a pretty permalink system set up on a site I've just built and nothing is having any effect. I either get a 500 error or the permalinks don't work and/or it breaks all the links to CSS and images while still giving a 404 if you try to use the permalink structure.

Here is my .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /main/index.php?act=$1&sub=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

I want it to convert links like `index.php?act=admin&sub=edit-product&id=5` to `/admin/edit-product/5` whilst including any in between. For example, if a URL has an ID call but not a sub call it will still work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

I have added `RewriteBase /` and it has now doing something, but the permalinks are not working properly.

Is there a way I can find out where the rewritten URL is actually pointing?

It seems that full URLs that use all the rewrite rules work, but not the URLs that only need some of them.

Comment: Look there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423258/php-mvc-with-better-htaccess/16423418

Comment: Okay, my code now is `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/([^/]+))?$ main/index.php?act=$1&sub=$3&id=$4`. It isn't breaking the CSS/image links but the redirects aren't working.

Comment: You may try redirect all to index.php with rule like that: RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]  And parse $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] inside your PHP application

Answer (score 1):

I use this .htaccess code for rewrite in my projects:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

This code pass exists request (for static files and etc) as is, but all other redirect to index.php. Request uri available int PHP as

```
$_REQUEST['REQUEST_URI']
```

In PHP we (or our framework) can parse it as we will.